# Detecting textfieldshouldreturn from Custom TableViewCell in TableViewController to Add New Row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to add a new row in my TableView when the user presses the return key inside the Custom TableViewCell, which includes a TextField. However, I cannot find a way to do so... how do I view the events of the TextField in my TableView so I can add the row?

My TableViewController

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomCellDelegate,
UITextFieldDelegate {

    var rowCount = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    ...

    // Doesn't Do Anything
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowCount-1, section: 1)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

    // Also does nothing
    func didReturn(cell: AddActivityTableViewCell, string: String?) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowCount-1, section: 1)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        view.endEditing(true)
        rowCount += 1
    }
```

My CustomTableViewCell

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func didReturn(cell: CustomTableViewCell, string: String?)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    public func configureTextField(text: String?, placeholder: String) {
        textField.text = text
        textField.placeholder = placeholder

        textField.accessibilityValue = text
        textField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
    }

    public func editableTextField(editable: Bool) {
        if editable == true {
            textField.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            textField.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    // This works
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        delegate?.didReturn(cell: self, string: textField.text)
        return true
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting your cell's `delegate` property in `cellForRowAt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the set delegate in the cell . Please find the code below which works fine for me

ViewController

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


var rowCount = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rowCount
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.textField.placeholder = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func didReturn(cell: CustomTableViewCell, string: String?) {
    rowCount += 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowCount-1, section:0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    view.endEditing(true)
}


}
```

Custom Cell

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func didReturn(cell: CustomTableViewCell, string: String?)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    public func configureTextField(text: String?, placeholder: String) {
        textField.text = text
        textField.placeholder = placeholder

        textField.accessibilityValue = text
        textField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
    }

    public func editableTextField(editable: Bool) {
        if editable == true {
            textField.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            textField.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    // This works
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        delegate?.didReturn(cell: self, string: textField.text)
        return true
    }

}
```